# Wygwam 2.6.3 - how to keep full style (image, table) from copying other article to wygwam field

Tags: wygwam

When I copy content of article (from other site) and paste it to my field (field type: wygwam), all styles is removed, only plain text remains. I need my article is the same to the article that I copy from other site. May somebody helps me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default you need to use paste from Word icon in the toolbar, not the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+V (or Cmd+V).

You can also edit the toolbar configuration within Wygwam and add an advanced setting for "forcePasteAsPlainText" and set it to No.  You can then use Ctrl+V (or Cmd+V) and your formatting is retained.

But this will mean that if a user copies from another source, it could contain all the other junk (e.g. copied from Word).